# Как в PHP вывести файл по url, не загружая его в память?

Tags: php, оптимизация, файловая-система

Здравствуйте. Передо мной встала задача выдавать пользователю файлы со стороннего сервера, однако память на VDS не бесконечная и скачивать файл целиком не вариант. fopen поддерживает url, но как через дескриптор отдать файл и при этом не загружать его в память?

P.S. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если выводить всё в echo, то данные будут сбрасываться в поток вывода минуя память?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
if ($fd = fopen($file, 'rb')) {
  while (!feof($fd)) {
    print fread($fd, 1024);
  }
  fclose($fd);
}
```

По поводу сброса данных не совсем понятен вопрос. Они не будут храниться в памяти во время всего выполнения скрипта. Если это имелось в виду то да, данные будут сбрасываться.
а вообще почитайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/)

Comment: Спасибо,  о что нужно! На счёт сброса я говорил про то, что при использовании print данные сохраняются во внутренний буфер или сразу уходят пользователю?